# Javascript RegExp to decrease all the numbers in a string by one

Tags: javascript, regex

The input is like this:

```
path = "html body div div:eq(2) p:eq(4)"
```

I want to decrease all the numbers in parenthesis by one, and get a string like

```
path = "html body div div:eq(1) p:eq(3)"
```

What should I do? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prinzhorn's answer is more concise, but I'd like to provide a "stricter" alternative (that also consider only numbers inside parenthesis, instead of anywhere).

```
path = path.replace(/\((\d+)\)/g, function(match, group1) {
    return "(" + (parseInt(group1,10) - 1) + ")";
});
```

Note: when you provide a function as the second argument of `replace`, you receive the full match and each capturing group as arguments, and whatever you return is inserted where the original match were. Here I'm matching the literal `(` and `)`, parsing the [captured] number in-between and decrementing it.

Comment: I would leave out the parseInt since we know it's a number an -1 will make doubly sure

Comment: @mplungjan Sure, but I was aiming for a strict example, so I'd rather avoid auto-casting from string to number (same reason I make the base `10` explicit). But YMMV...

Answer (score 3):

```
str.replace(/\d+/g, function(a) {return a - 1;});
```